# rule-based combination of sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a list:

```
lis = {{a},{1,2},{b},{3},{c,z},{d,e,f},{4}}
```

I would like to join adjacent members of this list when both are not integers (or lists of integers), producing:

```
res = {{a},{1,2},{b},{3},{c,z,d,e,f},{4}}
```

Testing all members of `lis` with `Head` results in `True` because each member of `lis` is itself a list.  Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Try `Join @@@ TakeList[lis, Length /@ Split[FreeQ[_Integer] /@ lis]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Flatten /@ Split[lis, And/* FreeQ[_Integer]] (* using @Coolwater's idea in a comment*)
SequenceReplace[lis, {a : {Except[_Integer]..}..} :> Join[a]]
SequenceReplace[lis, {a__?(FreeQ[_Integer])} :> Join[a]]
ReplaceRepeated[lis, {a___, b : Repeated[{Except[_Integer] ..}, {2, Infinity}], c___} :> 
  {a, Join[b], c}]
```

all give

> {{a}, {1, 2}, {b}, {3}, {c, z, d, e, f}, {4}}

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughts.  I am going to generalize them for my larger data set, I'll see which suggestion is faster.